# EEVEE light source reflection trough other reflections

Tags: 3d-view, light, eevee-render-engine, experimental-features

Any light source in eevee render reflects itself through anything in front of it.
[image: The scene in eevee, light passes straight through the reflection.]

In cycles, this problem does not exist (obviously)
[image: Scene in cycles, problem not present]

Enabling contact shadows Kind of fixes it, but it creates a lot of noise and doesn't always work.
[image: eevee and contact shadows. Note the inconsistency of the shadows.]

Am i missing something? Reflections are done with a plane reflection map,no screen space, everything seems to be in order.

Trying to render the scene properly gives me the same problem. I would like not to provide the scene file, the problem can be easily replicated on default blender 2.8 settings anyway.

I'd like to fix it.

Comment: I've just run into this issue. It appears yo;'ve run into a quirk/limitation of the renderer with your sun light source, but I find large lights look pretty horrible on reflective surfaces, regardless. I had to turn the specular to 0 on my main lights to get around it, but this makes the image feel a bit flat.

In your scene however it might work without making it look any different.